# How long do monsters take to despawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, I'm in a bit of a pinch. I'm on an SMP server, with 1.5 hearts and no food, but all the ingredients. I'm about to prepare some mushroom stew, but alas, I got chased and cornered by a creeper in a grief-protected house. If I open the door, I'm finished, but there's no other way. So, I'd like to wait for a creeper to despawn while I'm offline. How long would it take?

Comment: Does grief-protected house mean that you can't just dig out of there?

Comment: I think I read somewhere that Creepers despawn at noon?

Comment: @Bobby precisely. Also it means that I cannot place a crafting table to cook me some food to compensate for the kaboom. Also, problem solved :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you log off and there are no other players online, the server should immediately unload all chunks and all mobs within.

Comment: Doesn't the server always keep the spawn area loaded?

Answer (score -1):

If it is night time, and the creeper is in an area that will be exposed to daylight at dawn; when it gets light it will wander off in search of a dark place to hide in.

If the creeper is stood right outside the door, you can hit it through the door with a sword, without opening the door.

Alternately, if safe to do so; you can dig up and out above the creeper and whack it on the head. It can't jump up more than 1 block.

Comment: The hit-it-through-the-door trick no longer works.  It instead **opens** the door!

Comment: I can confirm that creepers **do not** care whether they're standing in the sun or not, and he said it's a grief protected house, meaning he can't dig up and out.